# Fluid Simulation Not Working, updated software and have done hours of research

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Running 2.92
Blender user since 2019.
I'm trying to fill a glass with liquid.
I can't get the fluid simulator to work consistently. I've been fiddling around with it and had limited successes, but can't repeat them with the exact same settings. When it has worked, the the liquid isn't visible when rendered and I can't figure out how to add a material property.
I've gone as far as to uninstall and reinstall the software.

File host on OneDrive
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Agn7HNH2KWg_bkA85v1K7lw-GeA

Comment: While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users with similar issues find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. disable guides
2. change resolution division to 90
3. change cache type to modular, check resumable
4. free data
5. bake data
6. check mesh
7. bake mesh

you get:

[image]

blend file:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the fluid to flow, but the fluid is s is still just blue pixels rather than an object as in your picture. Any ideas what I'm still not doing?

Comment: Did you check mesh?

Comment: I did. I get the feeling that I'm missing an add on or something. I made a new file and redid this with a hand full of cubes and again get nothing.

Comment: I can provide my modified blend file - if you want

Comment: I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @BruceBenikII Did you bake the mesh like Chris said in point 7? If you set the cache type to _Modular_, you first have to bake the fluid data, then bake the mesh afterwards. If you want to bake data and mesh at the same time you have to set the cache type to _All_.

Comment: i added the blend file

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann I baked the data under Mesh. This was my problem. Yesterday I thought there was only one bake button. Now I see there is two. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if you have set the cache type to _Modular_ then it's important to bake in the correct order. First _Bake Data_, then _Bake Mesh_ because the mesh needs data to be built upon. This way you can decide if the simulation looks like you want it before baking a mesh (or bubbles and what else there can be). However, if you've set the cache type to _All_, there is only one bake button: _Bake All_. This simulates the fluid and mesh (and bubbles etc.) all in one bake.

Comment: thank you Gordon for helping him! Looks like you deserved the green checkmark this time...!